# How to prevent ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following situation: page displays set of items, when user clicks on item, item details loaded through ajax request. What I want to do is to prevent ajax requests on further clicks, because information is already loaded.

I use jQuery and Rails 3 and my code looks something like this:

```
# view
- @items.each do |item|
  .item
    = link_to item.name, item_path(item), :remote => true

// js
$(function(){
  $('.item').bind('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status){
    ...
  });

  $('.item').bind('ajax:before', function(xhr){
    if (...) { // check if data already loaded
       // ???
    }
  });
});
```

Am I on a right way? Or there is another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I used wrong callback. The right callback is `ajax:beforeSend` with the following signature `function(event, xhr, settings)`. To prevent request sending I used `xhr.abort()` and it works fine.

http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag like `itemsLoaded = false` before ajax call. The moment the detail is loaded you can set that flag to `itemsLoaded = true`. The ajax call should only be performed when `if(!itemsLoaded){/* Do ajax to fetch details */}else return;`

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing you can do is to ensure that the click in the item only goes to the ajax function once. Ways to do this:

- The click event invokes a function that disables the binding of the item
- If you want to be sure, you do the same in the ajax success function
- After clicking the item, your function checks if the item info is already there. If it is, then it just returns.

Comment: Yes, this is a first solution I thought about, but there is too much code in it and it is not perfect for me. I look for something "unobtrusive" and "rails 3 way".

Answer (score 0):

One solution is you could create a boolean value then only make the ajax call if that value is false.

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable in the Ajax:success function like so...

```
AjaxSuccessVar=0;
$(function(){
    $('.item').bind('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status){
       AjaxSuccessVar = 1;
});

$('.item').bind('ajax:before', function(xhr){
   if (AjaxSuccessVar==0) { // check if data already loaded
      //then do your ajax function here
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) property as an indicator, e.g.:

```
  $('.item').bind('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status){
      $(this).data("loaded", true);

  }).bind('ajax:before', function(xhr){
      if (!$(this).data("loaded")) {
          // data has not been loaded
      } else {
          // do something
      }
  });
```

EDIT:

Try unbinding the click handler from the item 'trigger' once it has been clicked, e.g.:

```
$(".item").click(function() {
    $.ajax({ ... });
    $(this).unbind("click");
});
```

or perhaps upon successful completion of the request `ajax:success`

```
  $('.item').bind('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status){
      $(this).unbind("click");
  });
```

Comment: I don't need an indicator (I can check if data loaded or not), I need to prevent ajax request sending.

Comment: @Dmitry Maksimov - Ah, sorry I thought that is what you were after. I've updated my answer, hope it is more helpful now.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I found the answer.